# Rails: How to stub and test this external service call?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, webmock

Hello I have something like the following code inside a rails model:

```
class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
  def calculate_page_speed(url)
    browser = Watir::Browser.new :phantomjs
    start = Time.now
    browser.goto url
    finish = Time.now
    self.speed = finish - start
  end
end
```

Here is the test:

```
describe Page do
  context "calculate_page_speed for Page" do
    let(:google) { FactoryGirl.create(:page, url: "http://www.google.com") }

    it "should set the page speed" do
      google.speed.should be_nil
      google.calculate_page_speed
      google.speed.should_not be_nil
    end
  end
end
```

How can I stub effectively the external service for not calling it during the test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an approach like:

```
class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
  def calculate_page_speed(url)
    start = Time.now
    browser.goto url
    finish = Time.now
    self.speed = finish - start
  end

  def browser
    @browser ||= Rails.env.test? ? FakeBrowser.new : Watir.new(:phantomjs)
  end

  class FakeBrowser
    def goto
    end
  end 
end
```

but here you have test code in prod code which is not great.

---

A derived solution would be to inject the expected browser class in a config.

---

Finally you can just stub stuff:

```
Watir::Browser.any_instance.stub(:goto)
```

Comment: Yes I really don't like to change the production code just to test it, the last line of code seems more interesting.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think that `visiting a url and measuring the speed` belongs inside the `Page` model, setting the speed *is*, but not the actual calculation. So I would
create a class in `lib` that allows me to measure the speed of a url, and use that class instead. I would allow that class to be injected with a stub.

So something like this, in `lib\page_visitor.rb`:

```
class PageVisitor 

  def initialize(browser = Watir::Browser.new(:phantomjs)) 
    @browser = browser
  end

  def measure_speed(url) 
    start = Time.now
    @browser.goto url
    finish = Time.now
    finish - start  
  end

end
```

And the your `Page` becomes:

```
def calculate_page_speed(url) 
  self.speed = PageVisitor.new.measure_speed(url)
end
```

So with that setup, you can simplify your tests: in `Page` you have to check the right function is called, and likewise, in `PageVisitor` check that `goto` is called, without actually going to the page.

So, in `spec/models/page_spec.rb` write:

```
 let(:google) { FactoryGirl.create(:page, url: "http://www.google.com") }

 it("initial speed is zero") { google.speed.should be_nil }

 describe `calculating the speed` do 
   before do
     PageVisitor.any_instance.should_receive(:measure_speed).and_return(25)
     google.calculate_page_speed
   end 

   it "sets the speed correctly"        
     google.speed.should == 25
   end
 end
```

Using `any_instance` could be considered a smell, but in this case I think it is the easiest way to test it. If you really want to avoid it, instead of changing the code (I think the code is ok, no need to inject a `PageVisitor` imho), you could stub `PageVisitor.new` to return a specific `PageVisitor`, and then you can just stub `measure_speed` on that instance.

In your `spec/lib/page_visitor_spec.rb` write

```
 describe PageVisitor 

   class FakeBrowser 
     def goto(url)
       sleep 1
     end
   end

   let(:page_visitor) { PageVisitor.new(FakeBrowser.new) } 

   it "measure the speed" do 
     page_visitor.measure_speed.should_not be_nil
   end
 end
```

This should get you started.

Comment: Thanks, I actually have it in a concern the calculate_page_speed method as I am also using it in other models as well.